# Java swing - exercicio

Tags: java, swing

Estou com dúvida em relação ao Container, gostaria de saber se a forma que fiz está correto.

```
public class Exercicio2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JLabel lblTitulo = new JLabel(); 
    JLabel lblLogin = new JLabel();
    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel(); 
    JTextField jTFLogin = new JTextField();
    JPasswordField jPFPassword = new JPasswordField();
    JButton btnOk = new JButton();
    JButton btnCancelar = new JButton();        
    JFrame jFrameLogin = new JFrame();          
    Container container = jFrameLogin.getContentPane();
    jFrameLogin.setContentPane(container);
    container.setLayout(null);
    lblTitulo.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD, 12));
    lblTitulo.setBounds(90, 20, 180, 185);
    lblTitulo.setForeground(Color.red);
    container.add(lblTitulo);
    lblLogin.setText("Insira seu login!");
    container.add(lblLogin);
    lblPassword.setBounds(20, 90, 53, 15);
    container.add(lblPassword);
    jTFLogin.setBounds(80, 90, 210, 20);
    jTFLogin.setText("Insira seu login!");
    container.add(jTFLogin);
    jPFPassword.setBounds(80, 90, 210, 20);
    container.add(jPFPassword);
    JPanel jPanelBotoes = new JPanel();
    jPanelBotoes.setBounds(30, 120, 280, 60);
    jPanelBotoes.setLayout(null);
    jPanelBotoes.setBackground(Color.blue);
    container.add(jPanelBotoes);
    btnOk.setBounds(70, 20, 47, 23);
    jPanelBotoes.add(btnOk);
    btnCancelar.setBounds(150, 20, 75, 23);
    btnCancelar.setToolTipText("Sair do Programa");
    jPanelBotoes.add(btnCancelar);   
    }}
```

O exercício pede:

jFrameLogin: utilize o pack(); Ajuste o Container intermediário para setLayout(null);

Comment: O que você já fez? Qual sua duvida?

Comment: Eu não sei fazer a parte da letra "d", não consegui fazer nada somente criei a classe e os componentes, quando chega na parte do container intermediário não consegui compreender como faz

Comment: Principalmente essa parte: setar o tamanho (pack( )); setar a visibilidade (setVisible(true); lembre-se de delcarar um container intermediário e associá-lo ao container frame, utilizando o método getContentPane(), setar o Layout para nulo;

Comment: Não existe isso de container intermediario. O que esse enunciado quer dizer é pra você criar um container qualquer(Com jpanel, imagino) e setar como contentpane, que é o container principal do jframe. `pack()` não vai fazer nada nesse código seu, porque você não está utilizando layout e nem tamanho preferidos com `setPreferredSize`

Comment: tenho que fazer então dessa forma?

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel container = new JPanel();
container.add(frame)
é dessa forma?

Comment: Não. `frame.setContentPane("aqui você define um container"). `contentpane é do frame, você não adiciona uma janela do tipo frame dentro de nada, porque ela é [top level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html). Seria melhor você editar a pergunta e deixar apenas o pedaço do exercicio que te gerou duvida, e adicionar o que já fez do código.

Comment: Então fiz o outro exercício que é menor e editei a pergunta.

Comment: Aliás, qual é a sua dúvida? Não vi problema algum com o código, a não ser você utilizar a classe Container pra recuperar o contentpane e depois setar como contentpane.

Comment: Saber se estava correto, mas como vc disse que não tem nenhum problema, blz! Vlw

Comment: Tem um probleminha sim, veja o que eu escrevi no final do comentario. `Container container = jFrameLogin.getContentPane(); jFrameLogin.setContentPane(container);` esse trecho não está fazendo nada, é totalmente descartavel no seu código. Acho que a ideia do seu professor não era essa, era de você criar um JPanel e usar ele como container.

Comment: Quando eu disse Container, era pra você utilizar um componente com essa caracteristica, não necessariamente esta classe. JPanel é um container, por exemplo. Acho que era pra você usar ele pra adicionar tudo e depois defini-lo como contentpane do jframe.

Comment: Então eu tinha visto essa parte, descartei o jFrameLogin.setContentPane(container), mas entendi a questão que falou referente ao uso da classe Container, poderia ter utilizado um JPanel e usar ele como container, mas deu certo aqui. Vlw